# Supervisor XML-RPC encrypt connection

Tags: xml-rpc, supervisord

I'm using the [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/api.html) XML-RPC API to control my processes,
Is there any option to encrypt the communication using SSL or something else?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not at the moment. The API uses an internal webserver. What you can do is enabling basic auth, but that does not encrypt your content.

Why would you like to do it anyway?

Comment: Hi, I would like to be able to connect to the server and run supervisor commands but it is dangerous to expose this feature without any encrypt protocol.

Comment: As I said above, the server itself requires authentication. So unless you are under a Man in the Middle attack, you are safe. If you want better security, you can either SSH into server and user supervisorctl, or create website which supports controlling Supervisor and protect that site with SSL and password. Indirect connection to a service is alway more secure.

Comment: Or, if you want to restart/start/stop commands, you can use the webinterface that supervisor provides. It is also protected by basic auth. You can improve security, by allowing clients to connect from localhost and creating an SSH tunnel to the server.

Comment: Last, but not least: I am working on a monitor like solution: https://github.com/supervisorphp/monitor. Currently I don't have too much time for it, but I plan to make it more featureful. Hope these things help.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any screenshots of your monitor?

Comment: Not yet. As I said, it is not completely ready yet. Also, to make it fully working, I have to finish the HTTP Adapter and the XML RPC package I participate in. Then I can move on with my supervisor client.

Comment: Ok, thanks, waiting to see the final result. Will be nice if you will implement the twiddler adapter in it.

Comment: I plan to support third party extensions in my API client.